# Использование нескольких case в switch в PHP

Tags: php, switch, case

Хочу использовать несколько `case` в `switch`, указывая значения в переменной через запятую или массивом.

Возможно ли это сделать без лишних танцев с бубном?

Answer (score 3):

Список операторов для исполнения в секции case также может быть пустым, что просто передает управление списку операторов в следующей секции case.

```
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        echo "i меньше чем 3, но неотрицательный";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "i равно 3";
}
```

Источник: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php